# Ide for kotlin that I can run on my mobile device

Tags: kotlin, mobile, ide, device

I'm looking for an IDE that I can run on my mobile device that supports kotlin anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'd like to know of one, too!  (For Android, anyway.  Also, any way to run my existing command-line Java programs...)

Comment: Dcoder seems to be nice on android. But still it is not really comfortable to code on mobile device unless you have separate keyboard. But if you do, it is much better to have small laptop which is comparable by means of size with ipad with keyboard

Comment: [Some](https://igg.me/at/geminipda) Android phones [do](https://igg.me/at/gogocosmo) have a rather good keyboard built in…  But with all that computing power, surely there must be a way to write code on the device _itself_, without using up time and data sending it all to AWS?  (For example, you can run the old Jikes Java compiler; but I can't see how to run the Java .class files it generates.)

Comment: On android you could try using termux and chroot into ubuntu or other distro. After that, it should be mostly free reign, I don't think there's anything more usable than (n)vim and its kotlin plugins (that way you will never need mouse-like movements, only keyboard), in it, though. You could theoretically install whole DE and then just use IntelliJ... There's no reason why XFCE or i3 wouldn't work, not sure about IntelliJ on ARM though.